# How run two full-fledged window in IDEA? (or WebStorm/PyCharm/PhpStorm...)

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have two windows of JetBrains IDEA (or of WebStorm or of any other JetBrains IDE) opened.

How to make the second window to be equally fully equipped as the first window?

Now, only first window is fully-fledged. Second window is missing all the "tool windows" (tool bars).

I am usually working  on two different issues of one project. 
So I would need to have opened the files of the first issue in the first IDEA window - and the files of the second issue to be opened in the second IDEA window.
All the files are from the same project. 
(I do not need to have any file opened in both IDEA windows, usually)

Comment: You can not open two main IDE windows for the same project. Only as detached editor. Why do you need it? If you are using [Task management](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-tasks-and-context.html) - there is a feature of [**Contexts**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-tasks-and-context.html#work-with-context) that you may save and switch between.

Comment: @Andrey   OK, it is what I need, something like "workspaces" in programmers editors. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in [comment of @Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412451/how-run-two-full-fledged-window-in-idea-or-webstorm-pycharm-phpstorm/62414719#comment110382382_62412451):

> You can not open two main IDE windows for the same project. Only as detached editor. Why do you need it? If you are using [Task management](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-tasks-and-context.html) - there is a feature of [**Contexts**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-tasks-and-context.html#work-with-context) that you may save and switch between.